# Nested Serializer Problem in showing reverse

Tags: python, django

I defined this model:

```
class city (models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.ForeignKey(state,related_name='state', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city_name
```

and this serializer:

```
class citySerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = city
        fields = ('city_name')
```

If I add the state to my serializers field it shows me state_id of the table but I want it to show me state_name(another field of the state table )
I found this tutorial:https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/
but here inside parent model shows child model item,
I want inside child model show parent name(reverse of what tutorial do)
how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define your serializer like this:

```
class citySerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    state = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = city
        fields = ('city_name', 'state')
    def get_state(self, instance):
        return instance.state.state_name
```

[DRF documentation on SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

remember, Using this method, will cause additional query to database to fetch state_name from state table, if you didn't prefetch related states already.

Comment: I did this but it shows me an error: city has no attribute state

Comment: @AnahitaEsfandiaryfard so check your model, make sure state field actually is in the city model with the correct indentation.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?If it does, please mark it as solution.
thanks